# Sum Excel Distinct Values

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I know how to do this with MySQL, but am at a loss as to how (or even if possible) within MS Excel.  I am running Excel version 14 on Windows (part of Office Professional 2010).

I have a table with two columns...for example one containing phone numbers and the other containing integers (length of phone calls).  There are multiple calls from each phone number, so those numbers would likely appear multiple times.  I am trying to SUM the total number of minutes per distinct phone number.  How can I do this in Excel?

```
-------------------------
|  number  |  duration  |
-------------------------
| 1234567  |  8         |
| 2345671  |  5         |
| 1234567  |  12        |
| 3456712  |  5         |
| 3456712  |  47        |
| 1234567  |  15        |
| 1234567  |  4         |
-------------------------
```

So the end result would be something like:

```
-------------------------
|  number  |  duration  |
-------------------------
| 1234567  |  39        |
| 2345671  |  5         |
| 3456712  |  52        |
-------------------------
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Houari Perhaps...but having never used one before i am at a loss how to even start with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-create-a-pivottable-report-HA010359471.aspx) is how to achieve this using pivot table.

I just created a 20 seconds screencast [here](http://youtu.be/YOweH9bhr60).

Comment: Thanks.  I found a way with "Subtotal" in Data>Outline...but will read up on Pivot Tables for next time.

Comment: The screen-cast was helpful.  Thanks!  I actually tried the pivot table using the answer by @Don Pratt but cannot select BOTH of you as the correct...sorry Don!

Answer (score 2):

In column C use the SUMIF() Function like this:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,$A2,B:B)
```

This would give the total for every Phone#.
I understand the benefits of the previous answers, but depending on the users needs this might be what is being sought.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a pivot table for this.  Select your data (with headings) and click the Pivot Table button on the Insert ribbon.  Use the "number" field for row labels box and "duration" for the values.

Comment: This worked, however i cannot get it to sort by the "Sum of Duration" column...there is an auto-sort on the phone number column, but if i try to highlight the Sum column the "Sort and Filter" button is greyed out in the toolbar.

Comment: Try selecting one of the values in the "Sum of duration" column and then clicking the Sort button on the Pivot Table Options ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

I found something under the "Data" Tab in the "Outline" section called "Subtotal" which has done it.   I just highlighted my two columns, and clicked "Subtotal" and it created group subtotals auto-magically.