# Excel, Total of products with sum

Tags: excel, sum

I want a list with a total function from all the products I need on that day, with the sum of it.

So say I've this table:

```
Product | Sum
Egg       6
Egg       3
Meat      2
```

So I want a function that can return the total of a whole list under my list.
So the total would be:

```
Egg       9
Meat      2
```

So I can see in 1 eyecatch which stuff I need to have with me for that day. Is this possible in Excel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum Excel Distinct Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819693/sum-excel-distinct-values)

Comment: Ah thanks! sorry for duplicate post... Didn't find it

Comment: No problem, it wasn't that easy to find it. I tried it and it works. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should use **SUMIF()**, go 
[here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx) for detailed information.

Comment: you need a new SUMIF for each product, it's much more easier with pivot table

Answer (score 0):

If the products are going to change over time use a PivotTable. If not:

```
=SUMIF(Products!B:B,Products!A:A,A2)
```

Where Products!B:B is your list of values with duplicate products, Products!A:A is your list of products with duplicates and A2 is your product to sum up against.